# Error: Element "Element1" is not a known element. this can occur if there is a compilation error in website

Tags: asp.net, html, infragistics

```
<%@ Register   TagPrefix="uc3"  TagName="AccountDetailCustomerBook" Src="/Controls/AccountDetailCustomerBook.ascx" %>

<%@ Register    TagPrefix="uc2" TagName="AccountDetailHistoryChart" Src="/Controls/AccountDetailHistoryChart.ascx" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="AccountDetailAssetChart" Src="/Controls/AccountDetailAssetChart.ascx"  %>

<%@ Register   TagPrefix = "uc4" TagName = "DetailsAnnuity"  Src= "/Controls/DetailsAnnuity.ascx" %>
```

Using infragistics i have this error popping n below is the code how am using the control.
how can i remove this error?

`<uc3:AccountDetailCustomerBook ID="AccountDetailCustomerBook1" runat="server" />` so am using it like this. It says: element "accountdetails customerbook" is not a known element and its showing the error for all the controls.

Comment: <uc3:AccountDetailCustomerBook ID="AccountDetailCustomerBook1" runat="server" /> so am using it like this..it say element "AccountDetailsCustomerBook" is not a know element and its showing the error for all the controls

Comment: are you positive that the page/control that this code is in has a subdirectory named "Controls"? Post your directory structure.

Comment: yes they r in sub directory controls

Comment: check AccountDetailCustomerBook.ascx to be sure that every tag in it has no errors. If you messed up a closing tag or something, and AccountDetailCustomerBook.ascx can't compile correct you would get the error message you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and resolved it by including a tilde ~ character at the beginning of the src location.

For instance, register your 4 controls as follows:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc3" TagName="AccountDetailCustomerBook" Src="~/Controls/AccountDetailCustomerBook.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc2" TagName="AccountDetailHistoryChart" Src="~/Controls/AccountDetailHistoryChart.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="AccountDetailAssetChart" Src="~/Controls/AccountDetailAssetChart.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc4" TagName="DetailsAnnuity" Src="~/Controls/DetailsAnnuity.ascx" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually declare `AccountDetailCustomerBook1` in your designer.cs file then build your project. You will see a more related error for this problem.